# Task List Throws "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Tags: c#, task

Creating a list of Tasks to run parallel like this:

```
if (call.Item.PictureDetails != null)
{
    List<Task> lstTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var url in call.Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL.Cast<string>().ToList())
    {
        var newTile = AddNewPicTile(url);
        lstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {
            UploadPicture(newTile);
        }));
    }
    // Run all pic upload tasks in parallel...
    await Task.WhenAll(lstTasks);
}
```

Execution throws "Collection was modified..." exception but I can't figure out why.    I use similar code to this elsewhere in my app where I perform a while() loop that reads data from a database and it works fine.   Like this...

```
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                RadTileElement newTile = AddNewPicTile(rdr["PictureUrl"].ToString());   //...must create this var here otherwise we won't be able to access rdr from a background thread (it will be closed by then)
                
                lstTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => {
                    UploadPicture(newTile);
                }));
            }
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    conn.Close();
}

// Run all pic upload tasks in parallel...
await Task.WhenAll(lstTasks);
```

What is it about the string list that could cause it to yell at me like that?

Comment: *but I can't figure out why* - because something somewhere is modifying the collection while something somewhere is enumerating it. Which collection is complaining? Don't forget that enumerations happen that you cannot see; `ToList()` enumerates, for example

Comment: Try: `List<string> list = call.Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL.Cast<string>().ToList(); foreach (var url in list)`

Comment: @PoulBak - I did try that syntax with no change in result.

Comment: @CaiusJard - it's not clear which collection is complaining.   Looking at the call stack, it's in   mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl and a bunch of other system level objects...tracing backward all the way to my calling method (which has no collections).     So I'm assuming it has something to do with the List<Task> collection that is executing from Task.WhenAll()

Comment: Post the stack and the definitions of AddNewPicTile and UoloadPicTle. Do any of these methods called here use a shared list? If you turn on "break when thrown" for all exceptions (debug menu>> windows >> exception settings >> tick next to CLR exceptions) does va break at a different place?

Answer (score 0):

Actually - problem was not related to List.  Not even in the code posted.    Thanks to Caius Jard who got me looking elsewhere for it.